# Unplugged external drive while Bitlocker encrypting it; now I can't access it

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, encryption, bitlocker

I was encrpyting my external 2TB hardrive using windows 7 bitlocker. While the progress was at 13.05% I accidently removed the cable of the drive. After replugging the cable the encryption process didn't showed up. Ever since I try to connect my Hardrive  it shows the drive is bitlocker locked. But I cannot unlock or decrpyt the drive. The bitlocker software stops responding when i connect my hardrive.

I have Extremely Important data in the hardrive. Hope that someone can help me out.

I promised myself that I will never mess with Bitlocker again in my life.

Comment: You are out of luck.  There isn't a great deal that can be done.  I **hope you have backups.**

Comment: Actually, the last 86.95% is probably there fine. It all depends on in which order the Bitlocker encryption process encrypts the data, though. **If** it's sequential, at worst you should be able to zero out the first ~ 261 GB (2 TB \* 0.1305) of the partition (on some other system) and then use run of the mill recovery tools to recover the rest. If it starts out by encrypting things like the MFT, this might be trickier, but *might* still be doable. Look at the [data-recovery](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery), hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery and file-recovery tags.

Comment: Also, **make a byte-level copy of the drive** before you do anything with it. Restoring from a backup is probably the easiest, quickest and surest way to recover your data. As it was so important, I *hope* it's safe to assume that you have a recent backup. If you don't, and if you don't feel certain that you know **exactly** what you are doing, enlisting the services of a data recovery company might be your best bet. It shouldn't be ridiculously expensive at least, given that the drive itself is most likely perfectly functional (logical damage only) and you can tell them what to recover from.